# How to hide trim status bar controls programatically in RCP.

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I have a combo control created in the trim status bar using eclipse RCP. I have multiple perspectives in the application. Please suggest a way to hide the combo control in the status bar for a particular perspective programatically (not via plugin.xml).
P.S: I am using NEON eclipse.

Comment: Are you using E4 or prior RCP version?

Comment: If previous version use ```PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().addPerspectiveListener()``` when you can listen the perspective changes and act accodingly. If E4, look at the suggestion at https://stackoverflow.com/a/38968312/1651350

Comment: How are you creating this control?

Comment: the control was added via plugin.xml.                                                 in org.eclipse.ui.menus -> trim.status (menu contribution) -> statusbar (toolbar) -> combo (control). I am using E4.